# how i can get one row without checking all rows like 100000 records in mysql table using index?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, indexing

i need to Select employee name is "Pandiyan".

my question is ,i need to check all the rows in a table or any other option to get quickly without checking 100000 records in a table.

Comment: use select statement

Comment: If you have an index, but it is not being used effectively, you need to provide more info.  Start with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` you are using.  There could be something subtle inhibiting the use of the `INDEX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an index to the name column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON employee(name)
```